# At what temperature is a food Boleya in the utensil

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk, kashering-kosherization

Say I have a pot that I used for beef soup. Then an hour later I forgot I used the pot for meat and I decide to make soup with cheese. I throw the cheese in it and put it on the fire. About 5 *seconds* later I remember I used it for meat. What is the Halacha, does the pot need to be kashered, and what is the Halacha regarding the cheese.

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4235

Comment: @doubleaa http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4307

Comment: I think the correct answer is CYLOR.

Comment: what temperature did the pot become? could be only the pot needs to be kashered. i think we assume the blia is inside the walls of the pot uniformly so the part in contact with fire could have heated enough.

Answer (score 1):

it is the temperature of [Yad Soledes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5171/what-is-the-actual-temperature-of-yad-soledes)

see shulchan aruch yora daia 92.7,8 95.1 and [105.2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4307)