# Is there a "5 second rule" for foods becoming non-Kosher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, time, shiurim-measurements

OK so I don't actually mean a 5 second rule.  But is there an amount of time that it takes for something hot that comes in contact with a non-Kosher utensil or surface to become not kosher?  For example, if something falls out of my frying pan and touches the range surface (which is not Kosher as it is constantly getting splattered by milchig and fleishig), and I grab it right away, is it too late?

I'll CMLOR for any practical real-life scenarios.

Comment: See YD 92:1 to start though i'm pretty sure this is a dupe

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36586/759

Comment: @DoubleAA very similar, but in that case nothing is hot.

Comment: Your range surface is probably Eino Ben Yomo so the food should be fine to eat, though you can't return it to the pot.

Comment: @DoubleAA that only helps if it was clean

Comment: @shmuel Meh. Anything on the surface of the range is probably too burnt to be Taam Lishvach.

Answer (score 6):

The Chamudei Daniel has the famous opinion that for things that the Shulchan Aruch says "it becomes not kosher immediately", that means "if you don't pull them out immediately." More like a 2-second rule or so.

Comment: +1 because that's what I was going to say! (I think I _only_ know the famous stuff, so this is literally the only _halacha_ I have ever heard from that source.)

Comment: @WAF yeah that's pretty much what puts the Chamudei Daniel on the map for most of us. Actually I think he has one or two notable stances in Taharas HaMishpacha as well. (Sort of like "the Or Zarua's opinion" -- to some of the world, that's the heter on chadash grown by non-Jews; and to others, it's the extra veset.)

Comment: @Shalom You may be thinking of the Bach. The Or Zarua (nor any Rishon whose name a 12th grader might have heard of) did not permit Chadash grown by non-Jews. The Chamudei Daniyel is more familiar to me at least from his famous opinions in Hilchot Mezuzah. To each his own :)

Answer (score 0):

I take your question that you are asking that according to halocho, how much time do we need to consider that the taste had already halochakly traveled?

It seems from [Shulchan Aruch - Yora Deaya 92:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4237) (about a milk falling onto a peace of meat in a hot pot, and that if you were mixing right away or you closed the pot right away the rest of pot combines with peace (we use the whole pot to mivatel the drop))

that it is **instant** (**but maybe the time it takes to close the cover of a pot** see below. (but it seems that the Taz (there) holds that it is instant))

Rough partial translation:

... if mixed from beginning (when the drop fell) ... ramo ... if he mixed (the pot) in the beginning or **covered** (the pot) right away the pot...

PS And when we kasher something with hagolo I understand that it is **instantly** kosher.

Comment: I asked my maggid shiur in ta'aruvos even more specifically, and also was informed that ta'am indeed spreads instantly, i.e. exceeds the speed of light! :-)

Answer (score 0):

(physically maybe it takes time but legally (halochekly)) it is **instant**

why should heat be different than ([Shulchan Aruch - Yora Deaya 96.1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4264)) cutting a (spicy) radish that after one cut (probably even if the knife is very sharp so very fast) we say that the taste traveled kdai nitila (the thickness of a finger)?

Comment: No, we say the taste MIGHT have traveled kdai nitila, just our custom is to always assume the worst and not check.

Comment: @DoubleAA yes not physically traveled but legally, considered as traveled. As the question that it becomes legally not kosher (because the taste MIGHT have traveled (and it is so binding that it is even not ball tashkis))

Comment: (which is by far ashkenazims most annoying chumra. and people like to complain about kitniyos!) This only answers about Kedei Netila. What about in the OP's case where you might need Kedei Kullo?

Comment: (@DoubleAA I hope you are shefardi, if not I understand that this site is for Torah and in Torah, halocho is not annoying (a Jew can and should control what annoys him) it is the will of HKB"B)(are you referring to the law that Ashkenazim do not rely on a goy for taste, if not what chumra are you referring to?) why should kedei kullo be different? (see ps in my first answer) if you theoretically have a stone pot with walls 1 foot wide I understand (I might be mistaken) that you can kasher it by just dipping it into a big pot of boiling water and take it out and it will be kosher

Comment: (you do not need to wait until the stone in the middle of the pot gets hot)

Comment: I have no idea why you just made up that Halacha can't be annoying. In any event, there is no law that Ashkenazim cannot rely on a non-Jew for taste-tests; there is just a custom to be Machmir not to rely on them. It's definitely higher than Kitniyot on my burninate list.

Comment: @DoubleAA you are right i was not careful it says minhag so please answer http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48138/minhag-means-law-when-in-shulchan-aruch

Comment: @DoubleAA and this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48139/is-a-jew-aloud-to-be-annoyed-at-torah