# Is there an objective numerical temperature to "yad soiledes boy"

Tags: shabbat

being that feeling differs from person to person is there an objective numerical temperature to "yad soledes boy" and how is this established?

Comment: Do you think that Hazal meant one? Why would they think in those terms? Or do you mean to ask whether modern poskim give estimates for the _shiur_?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5171/8775.

Comment: @mevaqesh Seems like an actual dupe to me.

Comment: @DonielF What it is and how it is established are not really the same question.

Comment: @Loewian So it’s at least a half-dupe.